# Particle moving in a 2D box

Tags: differential-equations

does anyone know, how classical mechanics (likes forces, velocities or boundary conditions) could be integrated in a code? do you maybe have some ideas how i can write a code for my particle in a 2D box with this characterisations?

Best Regards

Comment: You need to show your preliminary work.

Comment: The ODE solvers, `DSolve` and `NDSolve` work well for such problems; read their documentation.  For examples, use the search function. to find questions on this site dealing with classical mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this what you are looking for?  Alternative solutions could use WhenEvent inside of NDSolve.

Hopefull, the names of

```
reflect[ finalPosition_, wallPosition_] := 
 2 wallPosition - finalPosition

moveBall[{currentPosition_, currentVelocity_}, 
  dt_, {left_, right_}] :=
  Module[
  {newPosition  = currentPosition + currentVelocity dt, 
   newVelocity = currentVelocity},
  If[newPosition > right, 
   newPosition = reflect[newPosition, right];
   newVelocity = -newVelocity
   ];
  If[newPosition < left, 
   newPosition = reflect[newPosition, left];
   newVelocity = -newVelocity
   ];
  {newPosition, newVelocity}
  ]

backGround =
 With[{left = -1.1, right = 1.1, bottom = -1.1, top = 1.1, dw = 0.1, 
   wallLength = 2.4},
   Graphics[
   {
    Rectangle[{left - dw, -wallLength/2}, {left , wallLength/2}],
    Rectangle[{right , -wallLength/2}, {right + dw, wallLength/2}],
    Rectangle[{-wallLength/2, bottom - dw}, {wallLength/2, bottom}],
    Rectangle[{-wallLength/2, top}, {wallLength/2, top + dw}]
    }
   ]
  ]

{positionX, positionY} = {0.1, .3};
{velocityX, velocityY} = {1, Sqrt[2]};

Dynamic[
 Show[backGround, Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{positionX, positionY}, .1]}]]
 ]

Do[Pause[0.01];
 {positionX, velocityX} = 
  moveBall[{positionX, velocityX}, .01, {-1, 1}];
 {positionY, velocityY} = 
  moveBall[{positionY, velocityY}, .01, {-1, 1}], {i, 1, 1000}
 ]
```